# ESXI to run Windows 7 or 10?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, esxi

Can I use ESXI to run a Windows 7 or 10 VM which acts like a desktop? Is is possible to connect a monitor, keyboard and mouse to the server and use it like a normal desktop?

I don't have any experience with ESXI. The server/desktop that will run this all will be used for several purposes, and this is one of them. I think this is the best option for me, but I don't know yet. Maybe multi-boot is better, but if this works then I prefer it.

ESXI makes it possible to run multiple VMs at the same time. How can I change which VM connects with the monitor, mouse and keyboard? Is that covered by the ESXI manager, and is it possible to set that externally via SSH or some similar service?

Comment: You typically manage ESXi VMs with something like the VSphere Web Client.  You need to do more research on what ESXi is exactly, your questions do not make logical sense, in the case of a Type I hypervisor.

Comment: If you were to use ESXi, it means you are booted into the ESXi OS, which means you would have the ability to start and create the VMs and thats about it.  In order to get a console that would require vSphere, in order to project that VM onto your zero client, would require VMWare Horizon. You would not attempt to manage a ESXi VM with just ESXi, and you wouldn't connect a keyboard and mouse to it.  If you want that capability use a Type II Hypervisor like VMWare Workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ESXi console (the keyboard and monitor connected to the host computer) cannot view/control the actual virtual machines.The VM interfaces must be viewed on a physically different machine.

There are hypervisors that allow you to have a desktop OS running on the host and then VMs running inside that OS, which would then allow you to use a single computer and primary OS and then multiple VMs.

But, if you're working with ESXi then you'll need at least two physical computers to accomplish this: One to be the host which can run headless in a closet, and the other(s) to connect and view the VMs.